Why does $R_{a,\theta}S_L(a)=R_\theta S_L(a)+(1-R_\theta)a$?
I'm working on a problem,

Show that $R_{a,\theta}S_L(x)=T_c$, where $c=(1-R_\theta)(a-S_L(a))$.

Here $R_{a,\theta}$ is rotation by angle $\theta$ about point $a$; $S_L$ is reflection in line $L$; $T_c$ is translation by vector $c$.
[ETA: The context suggests the setting is either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'd be happy with an answer for either.]
The given solution includes the line $$R_{a,\theta}S_L(a)=R_\theta S_L(a)+(1-R_\theta)a$$ without further explanation of that line.
I don't follow. Could someone explain?

Is this problem set in $\Bbb{R}^2$? Is $1$ the identity map on $\Bbb{R}^2$?

@TheoBendit Yes, and I think so.

Note that $R_{a, \theta}(x) = a + R_\theta(x - a)$, so
$$R_{a, \theta}S_L(a) = a + R_\theta(S_L(a) - a).$$
Since $R_\theta$ is linear,
$$R_{a, \theta}S_L(a) = a + R_\theta S_L(a) - R_\theta a = R_\theta S_L(a) + (1 - R_\theta)a.$$
